# Problem with the Replace Function in Northwind Database Template

Tags: ms-access

Good day everyone, I have ms access 2007-2016 file format, I have recently downloaded the Northwind Database Template, I tried to run a query on some table, let's take table "Products" as example, it has a field named "Product Name" of type short text, if I try to run the following query
`SELECT Products.[Product Name], Replace([Product Name],"Northwind Traders ","") AS Product FROM Products;` 
The results of the second column will turn out all to be "#Error", it seems that it's the problem with this particular file, since I don't have problems with other files, but I don't know what's wrong with this Northwind Database.

Comment: From where did you download the file?

Comment: From access startup screen, Suggested searches: Northwind, and only 1 result comes up

Comment: I am using Access 2010. I don't see anything that says "Suggested searches". However, I do see Northwind in "Sample Templates" so I will use that one. The query works for me. Check if there are any MISSING libraries in the VBA editor References.

Comment: works in access 2016 using the northwind template as well

Comment: Can I send you my Northwind Database for you to try? Maybe through email or dropbox

Comment: You can post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db there.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkqubldke99yjyk/Database5.accdb?dl=0
This is my database

Answer (score 0):

that query should work.

You  could do a ctrl-g (jump to immediate window).
And from the menu go tools->References.

You should say see this:

[image]

there should not be any "missing" references.

Close the above reference window, and then try this option:

Open up the vb module called Utilites, and "dirty" the module.
(just hit enter key in a blank line - add a new blank line).

Say hit enter key here:

[image]

Now, from menu do this:
debug->compile

[image]

Does the database compile?

This sounds like a broken reference. But that should not occur from a fresh blank new template as you have.

Your query as posted works fine for me.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I followed your comment, and my database does compile, so is it a broken reference or not?

Comment: The first time I run this query, it states: you omitted an operand or operator, you entered an invalid character or comma, or you entered text without surrounding it in quotation marks.
Then I have to change all the commas with semicolons, and the results are just errors.